# Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

Tags: c#, silverlight, iframe, ssl-certificate

> I know this question has been asked here many times but I didn't find any solution to resolve my issue.

I've a `silverlight` application in which I've to show a `webpage`. For this purpose I'm using **WebBrowser** within a grid and passing `IFrame` to this webbrowser.

I pass a `URL`to `IFrame` that has **security certificate** problem and it gives me error

[image]

But when I paste same `URL` to browser, it gives me error
[image]

From here in browser, I can continue to the site by selecting second option `Continue to this website`.

Isn't there any way to `do same thing` in my `application`?? Same Error prompts over there and I can continue to the site by selecting second option?

I searched a lot on this but didn't find any solution either to resolve this issue or to prompt `recommendations`.

Is there any way out? any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might need to purchase a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't and there shouldn't be any. It's against  the security of a browser. When browser displays certificate error, it does it for a reason. Instead of looking for workarounds, fix the certificate problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a SSL certificate that comes from a trusted CA. If you prefer, you can try LetsEncrypt which offers free SSL for most browsers.